# How to detect IP conflict in WAN and best practices

Tags: dhcp, wan, network

I am working on a WAN setup. Normally, the user IPs are assigned using DHCP, but users accidentally set their IP to static, which can causes 2 computers in network have same IP in same subnet.

How can I detect this situation? And what is the best practices to handle?

Comment: There's not enough detail here to allow a proper answer. Please edit your question and add your topology (a diagram would help) kind of equipment used (brand / model / software version...) and what are you relation to the users.

Answer (score 1):

As @JFL said we probably need more details... (what is the DHCP server? Linux, MAC, Windows clients?, etc) However, since the duplication happens in the "LAN" (same subnet, even if it crosses WAN) I have few things to propose:

1. Use a scanner box: Have a job to periodically scan the whole LAN range (nmap maybe). Then use the ARP table of the box (after every scan) to read and temporarily store the IP/MAC address mapping. Cross-reference this with the DHCP leases. You should see MAC addresses matching an IP the DHCP does not know about! This might depend on the (hop) distance of the non-legit box, so you might need to deploy more that one scanners.
2. Have a passive ARP and DHCP/BOOTP sniffer in combination with a monitoring port on your switch so you can track IP to MAC resolutions. Remember which boxes used DHCP... If you notice a machine relying to an ARP request but never used a DHCP request, that is your statically configured box. In this case you might also need multiple sniffers...
3. IF you have a single gateway for that LAN, monitor the gateway. Contrary to the previous 2 ways you don't need to deploy anything. All you have to do is periodically poll the MAC address table of the gateway (filtered to the interface/vlan that you expect the duplication). You can do this with SNMP or SSH (depending on lots of things, like vendor, use of VRFs - more info here?)

Now, best practices - I am not sure... could be port security (MAC based registration on the network) on the switches, `iptables` (or similar) to block any MACs not known to the DHCP server, etc. Depending on you setup and security requirements, best practices can be a separate question!

Hope that helps, let me know if you have questions and will update the answer